# How can I make webpack embed my *.wasm for use in a web worker?

Tags: webpack, webassembly, webpack-5, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

I have some rust code that compiles to web assembly using `wasm-pack` and `wasm-bindgen`. I want to call into this code from a web worklet/worker. The entire app should eventually be just one single *.js file, with everything else inlined.

This is what I imagine my build process to look like:

1. Use `wasm-pack` to compile the rust code to *.wasm and *.js bindings (this step works just fine)
2. Use `webpack` to build a self-contained *.js file that I can load as a worklet/worker. The *.wasm must be included in this file. (this step fails)
3. Use `webpack` again to build my final app/package, inlining the worklet/worker file from step 2. (this step works just fine)

My problem is in step 2: I can't make `webpack` inline the *.wasm into the worklet/worker file.
I tried this in my webpack config:

```js
entry: {
    worker: {
        import: './src/worker.ts',
        filename: '../lib/worker.js',
    }
},

// ...

module: {
    rules: [
    
        // ...

        {
            test: /\.wasm$/,
            // 1st option: type: 'webassembly/sync',
            // 2nd option: type: 'asset/inline',
        },

        // ...

    ],
},
```

No matter what I do, `webpack` always emits two files, one `worker.js` with my worklet/worker script itself, and another one, `vendor_my_package_name_wasm_js.js` that contains just the *.wasm and its bindings. Obviously, when loading the `worker.js` as a web worker, it fails - the second file can't be loaded from the worker scope.

My goal is to include everything in `worker.js` and NOT have a separate file emitted. But how do I do that?

**Edit: Documenting steps towards a solution:**

Webpack native wasm-loading doesn't seem to allow inlining the wasm file. We can try to use a regular raw-loader:

```js
// in module.rules
{
    test: /\.wasm$/,
    loader: 'raw-loader',
},
```

This results in the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/my-module/my-wasm-file.wasm
Module parse failed: magic header not detected
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

This happens because there's still an implicit default rule that kicks in. [We can disable it by overwriting the default rules](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6725#issuecomment-372182505) to only consider `json` and `js` files:

```js
// in webpack.config.js
    module: {
        defaultRules: [
            {
                type: 'javascript/auto',
                resolve: {},
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/i,
                type: 'json',
            },
        ],
        rules: [
            // ...
            {
                test: /\.wasm$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
```

Now we finally have our worker bundled into a single *.js file! However, when loading it, we end up in this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

pointing to this piece of webpack-generated code:

```js
/* webpack/runtime/jsonp chunk loading */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        __webpack_require__.b = document.baseURI || self.location.href; // <<< error here
/******/        
/******/        // object to store loaded and loading chunks
/******/        // undefined = chunk not loaded, null = chunk preloaded/prefetched
/******/        // [resolve, reject, Promise] = chunk loading, 0 = chunk loaded
/******/        var installedChunks = {
/******/            "myModuleName": 0
/******/        };
/******/        
/******/        // no chunk on demand loading
/******/        
/******/        // no prefetching
/******/        
/******/        // no preloaded
/******/        
/******/        // no HMR
/******/        
/******/        // no HMR manifest
/******/        
/******/        // no on chunks loaded
/******/        
/******/        // no jsonp function
/******/    })();
```

For some reason webpack tries to support loading stuff dynamically (?). We can isolate the problem to this piece of code that was generated by `wasm-pack` as part of the javascript bindings when using the `--target=web` CLI argument:

```js
async function init(input) {
    if (typeof input === 'undefined') {
        input = new URL('my_wasm_file.wasm', import.meta.url);
    }
    const imports = {};
    // ...
```

Apparently the possibility of having to generate a URL makes webpack rely on `document` which is not available when loading the worker script in the worker scope. Uncommenting the `new URL()` part makes the `document` reference disappear from the webpack output.

Not sure where to go from here. Write my own wasm-loader? I worked on that for a while, base64 encoding the wasm file and inlining it as a string - but then I have to dramatically change the consumer code to manually load the wasm asynchronously. This means that I can't use the `wasm-bindgen` bindings anymore as they rely on either the `URL` part shown above (when using `--target=web`) or the bundling logic of webpack 5 (when using `--target=bundler`) which I can't get supported from my own simple wasm-loader attempts.
Essentially that means that I have to provide my own JS bindings, which is inconvenient.

There must be a better way - right?

Comment: I'm able to bundle js and wasm into one file unfortunately it's not quite working at runtime.   Did you turn on the webpack experiments for web assembly?

Comment: the webpack experiments for web assembly only "copy" the wasm to the output directory. I want the wasm to be embedded in the output *.js file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The solution

1. Build the wasm itself: `cargo build --target=wasm32/unknown/unknown`
2. Build the JS-bindings: `wasm-bindgen --out-dir=dist --target=web --omit-default-module-path my-wasm-package.wasm`.
3. Consume the wasm in your worklet script like this:

```js
import init, { /* other stuff */ } from 'my-wasm-package';
import wasmData from 'my-wasm-package/my-wasm-package.wasm';

const wasmPromise = init(wasmData);
```

4. Use this webpack config to build the worklet script into one single *.js file:

```js
// ...

module.exports = {

    // ...

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    configFile: 'tsconfig.json',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.wasm$/,
                type: "asset/inline",
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

#### Why it works

The core problem I observed was that the JS bindings generated by `wasm-bindgen` contain the `URL` keyword - which makes `webpack` initialise in such a way that it expects the `document` object to be defined. That object is undefined in the worklet scope, so initializing `webpack` would crash, even if we never entered the code section that contains the `URL`.

If we don't use `wasm-pack` to build the wasm and the bindings in one go, we can pass additional arguments to `wasm-bindgen` - mainly the `--omit-default-module-path` argument which removes the section with the `URL` from the bindings. Now `webpack` won't reference `document` when it initializes and we can use the bindings without modification.

From here it's simple: We bundle the wasm as a b64 encoded asset and pass it to the `init()` function that comes with the JS bindings.

Comment: I tried to recreate this code, but i run into this error. Do you have an idea to solve it? ```Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '__wbindgen_externref_xform__' in '/Users/maurits/code/lto/ownable-demo/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug'
 @ ../target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/ownable_demo.wasm```

Comment: Are you using `externref` somewhere in your rust code? I never saw this error, but I'm also not using any `externref`. I suggest you start with a simple hellow world example to get the rust => wasm => JS bundling to work, then add in your actual code to see where it breaks.

Comment: @TheSlowGrowth Is it possible somehow to export the JS bindings from your worklet script so that I can use them outside of the script? At the moment, it only works to put the business logic inside the worklet script which gets executed immediately when I load the script in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I could get accepted solution to be part of my build process, so I did this:

https://github.com/SonOfLilit/vscode-web-wasm-rust

It involved writing a `webpack` WASM Loader plugin (and patching `webpack` to make that possible, PR submitted) to use this loader:

```
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/wasm loading */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        __webpack_require__.v = (exports, wasmModuleId, wasmModuleHash, importsObj) => {
/******/            var vscode = require('vscode');
/******/            var wasmPath = __webpack_require__.p + wasmModuleHash + '.module.wasm';
/******/            var req = vscode.workspace.fs.readFile(vscode.Uri.file(wasmPath));;
/******/            return req
/******/                .then((bytes) => (WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importsObj)))
/******/                .then((res) => (Object.assign(exports, res.instance.exports)));
/******/        };
/******/    })();
```

as well as setting `__webpack_public_path__` in `activate` before trying to import the WASM:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  __webpack_public_path__ =
    context.extensionUri.toString().replace("file:///", "") + "/dist/web/";

  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "vscode-rust-web.helloWorld",
    () => {
      require("rust-wasm").then((rust: any) => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(rust.greet());
      });
    }
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71673305/3375765) is great for a situation that matches the context of the question exactly (you want to *build your own Rust code* into a WASM module and *then use it* in a worker). I faced the same exact error messages in a slightly different context, but I thought my findings may be of help here nonetheless.

My context was: I have a WASM dependency that has been built by *someone else* so it is less convenient to change the flags used to build the JS bindings (such as `wasm-bindgen`'s `--omit-default-module-path`). In my case WASM was not even built from Rust, but its JS bindings had the same `URL` markers as described in the question.

**DISCLAIMER: I'm neither a WASM nor a webpack expert, so I'm not aware of the full implications of the below approach. In my context it didn't cause unintended side-effects, but I'm not confident that's a sure thing.**

The solution was to specify a `baseUri` property for an `entry` in webpack's config:

```
entry: {
    worker: {
        import: './src/worker.ts',
        filename: '../lib/worker.js',
        baseUri: 'my:worker.ts',
    }
},
```

As of this writing the property doesn't seem to be present in the [official docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry), but has been [contributed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/15424).

This changes the webpack-generated code to

```
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/jsonp chunk loading */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        __webpack_require__.b = "my:worker.ts";
/******/        // ... rest remains the same as in the question's description ...
/******/    })();
```

This removes references to `document` and avoids the error at runtime.